# Returning single object using from ... in linq?

Tags: .net, linq

is it possible to change this query so that it does not return an Ienumerable List but a single object?
In my case it is guranteed a single object or null.

```
.First()
```

seems to be not available?

```
 var as= from s in entities.Subscriptions
        join or in entities.OrderRates on s.OrderRateId equals or.OrderRateId
        join oo in entities.OrderOfferings on or.OrderOfferingId equals oo.OrderOfferingId
        join ov in entities.OrderVendors on oo.OrderVendorId equals ov.OrderVendorId
        where s.CustomerId == customerId
        select new
        {...}
```

Comment: `(...).SingleOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.First()` will throw an exception if the source sequence is empty. So if your where condition is not resulting any items, you will get an exception.

You can use the `SingleOrDefault` method if you are sure there will be only a single item or null yields from your where condition.

```
 var customer = (from s in entities.Subscriptions
                         join or in entities.OrderRates on s.OrderRateId equals or.OrderRateId
                         join oo in entities.OrderOfferings on or.OrderOfferingId equals oo.OrderOfferingId
                         join ov in entities.OrderVendors on oo.OrderVendorId equals ov.OrderVendorId
                         where s.CustomerId == customerId
                         select new
                         { //your mapping for new annonymous object goes here}
                ).SingleOrDefault();
```

`SingleOrDefault`/`FirstOrDefault` resides in the `System.Linq` namespace. So make sure you have a using statement to import that namespace to the class where you are using this

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: thx! I did not use brackets around the from query, thats why I did not receive suggestions from resharper.